# How to give my own _id while inserting data in Elasticsearch?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, python-3.6, elastic-stack

I have a sample database as below:

| SNO | Name | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99123 | Mike | Texas |
| 88124 | Tom | California |

I want to keep my SNO in elastic search _id to make it easier to update documents according to my SNO.

Python code to create an index:

```
    abc = {
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 2,
        "number_of_replicas": 2
    }
}

es.indices.create(index='test',body = abc)
```

> I fetched data from postman as below:

```
{
"_index": "test",
"_id": "13",
"_data": {
    "FirstName": "Sample4",
    "LastName": "ABCDEFG",
    "Designation": "ABCDEF",
    "Salary": "99",
    "DateOfJoining": "2020-05-05",
    "Address": "ABCDE",
    "Gender": "ABCDE",
    "Age": "21",
    "MaritalStatus": "ABCDE",
    "Interests": "ABCDEF",
    "timestamp": "2020-05-05T14:42:46.394115",
    "country": "Nepal"
}
```

}

> And Insert code in python is below:

```
req_JSON = request.json 
input_index = req_JSON['_index']
input_id = req_JSON['_id']
input_data = req_JSON['_data']    
doc = input_data 
res = es.index(index=input_index, body=doc)
```

> I thought _id will remain the same as what I had given but it generated the auto _id.

Comment: Can you show your Python code that indexes your documents?

Comment: abc = {
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 2,
        "number_of_replicas": 2
    }
}

es.indices.create(index='test',body = abc)

Comment: You should update your question instead, it's more legible than in comments. Also the statement you showed only creates the index, but doesn't index documents. It's that statement that I'm interested in

Comment: @val I updated the question. Can you please look at once. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it [like this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py#example-use):

```
res = es.index(index=input_index, body=doc, id=input_id) 
                                                ^
                                                |
                                             add this
```

Comment: And via the `bulk` API..?

Comment: @jtlz2 please create a new thread showcasing your specific issue as this one was about the `index` method

Comment: I'm also interested how it happens via the `bulk` API. Do we have an open question for that?

Comment: @chocho.boss It's very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343237/elasticsearch-bulk-set-id/63343313#63343313